# Magento 2.3.1 server resources requirements

Tags: magento2, server-setup, magento2.3.1, webserver

I have a Magneto CE 2.3.1 installation whit 7 stores and a total of 24 store views, in each store I got ~60 000 product's, so that's almost ~1.440.000 of different product data. I'm using multi-source inventory with 8 sources.
Running indexer on schedule. If I import a CSV  file with 8000 rows ( SKU / price / custom_attribute ) it takes 1 days to reindex all the data.

What would be the server requirements to run this site in a decent manner?

Any suggestions or recommendations about what I can do to optimize is deeply appreciated!

---

Current SV  specs:

1 Dedicated DB SV (20cores) running MySQL 5.6.43

1 Hosting (master) SV running LiteSpeed

```
-php 7.2.4
-64 ram
-16 cores
```

1 Load balance SV

1 Slave SV (an HTML copy of master SV)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the **Indexer Optimization** steps provided in Magento Documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html. We are using Amazon RDS service for two instances where one is in **Magento 2.2.6** and has 55 stores with 50000 products in each store. The other is in **Magento 2.1.9** and has 35 stores with 40000 products in each store. When bulk changes are done through the script it takes about 45 minutes to 90minutes for the reindexing to complete. The Reindex is set to happen in Cron. The Server RAM capacity is 16 GB with 8 cores. Hope it will be useful for you.